# How can you define vectors with complex numbers?

Tags: vector-spaces

For real vector space, you can define vectors of $x$, $y$, or $z$ on Euclidean space

$$x=\left(x_1, x_2, x_3, \dots, x_n\right) \qquad y=\left(y_1, y_2, y_3, \dots, y_n\right)$$

For example, in 2-dimensional vector space, given $x=(1,2)$ and $y=(3,2)$, you just draw it.

What about complex numbers on higher dimensions and up to $n$-dimension?

Comment: You can define a [Vector Space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) over any [Field](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_(mathematics)). The complex numbers form a field, so you can define them much in the same way as with real numbers. Visualisation on the other hand, can get quite difficult.

Answer (score 0):

You can define them in the same way - a 2 dimensional vector space over the complex numbers would have vectors $(x,y)$ where $x$ and $y$ are complex numbers, for example $(1+i,2i)$. This works for $n$ dimensions, no problem. The only trouble might be that the complex numbers themselves can be viewed as a 2 dimensional vector space over the reals, and so a 2 dimensional complex vector space will in fact be 4 dimensional over the reals - which is difficult to visualize. :)

**Edit:**
As for your second comment, it would help to know what is the context of your questions. For two complex vectors $z=(z_1,...,z_n)$ and $w=(w_1,...,w_n)$ the so called Euclidean inner product is defined as $\sum z_i\overline{w_i}$, so that $<z,w>=\overline{<w,z>}$ holds as you've written. That's done to make sure that some properties deemed important can be generalized from the real Euclidean space to the complex variety. For example, if we were to use the standard inner product for complex numbers, we would get $<(1+i,1-i),(1+i,1-i)>=2i-2i=0$, and so the length of the nonzero vector $(1+i,1-i)$ would be $0$, which is something that is not seen as desireable.

Comment: so if I let z=a+bi, then For n-dimensional, I could say that z=(z1,z2,z3....zn) ?

Comment: and one more thing, If you let (x.y) => (1+i,2i) , inner product is 2i-2 , what about (y.x) ? I am so confused because there has to be conjugate sign over (y.x) so that (x.y)= conjugate of (y.x)

Comment: If you mean $z_k=a_k+b_ki$ for $k=1..n$, then yes, $z=(z_1,...,z_n)$ would be a valid complex vector in $n$ dimensions.